# R: Why does the 'space' character in an externally generated string have ASCII value 'NA'?

Tags: r, ascii, whitespace, utf

I'm working with some SurveyMonkey response data, which I'm importing from a .xlsx file.

Something along these lines was happening:

```
> unique(responseColumn)
[1] "This string"
[2] "Something else"

>(responseColumn == unique(responseColumn)[1])
[1] 25

>sum(responseColumn == "This string")
[1] 0

>unique(responseColumn)[1]
[1] "This string"

>unique(responseColumn)[1] == "This string"
[1] FALSE
```

Obviously that was confusing. I played around for a while and found that I could use

```
writeClipboard(unique(responseColumn)[1])
```

to catch the offending string and paste it into my code.

In the console, it looked exactly the same: "This string".

In my script editing window, however, it appeared as:

[image]

I copied the red dot to the clipboard and did some testing:

```
>readClipboard()
[1] " "

>readClipboard() == " "
[1] FALSE

>utf8toInt(" ")
[1] 32

>utf8toInt(readClipboard())
[1] NA
```

What is this mysterious character? I wrote the Survey Monkey questions and distinctly remember hitting 'space' on my keyboard when specifying this option. Other spaces in the response have remained as they were (In fact the response in question actually has multiple spaces IRL and only one of them has been converted into this mysteryChar). What's going on?

Comment: There is a multitude of white space characters besides a standard blank space. We can't say which one it is, but you probably should sanitize your input.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that the "red" dot is just some non ASCII, possibly UTF-8, character.  That you can't see it in R console does not mean that it still is not logically there in the Windows clipboard.  It could just mean that R console is not displaying UTF-8 characters correctly.

If your R tool is not displaying the character correctly, then consider configuring it to support UTF-8.